# Linux, AMD, Flash-video - is GPU-decoding possible at all?

Tags: linux, flash, gpu, ati

If it's possible - how to make ATI videocore to decode flash-video in archlinux?

P.S. please if you know that fact it's working somewhere somehow - just tell me about!
I googled all around and i can't find answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong forum. Better start here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI_Catalyst

Adobe flashplugin does *not* support VA-API. Therefore no ATI hw acceleration. It only supports VDPAU (nvidia).
You can use **`gnash`** to play flash videos with VA-API acceleration.